# Dhtmlx gantt changes project start date automatically

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

So I have this scenario with a screen like below:

[image: DHTMLX gantt chart]

The DHTMLX Gantt automatically changes the project start date to default to the first day of the Gantt chart if there are no children tasks. In this case, Phase 3 takes the start date from its sibling Phase 1 i.e Jan 29.

How can I stop this default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The tasks with the `project` type rely on the dates of their children. If there are no child tasks, projects obtain the dates from other tasks or from the current date.
You can read more about project tasks here:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__task_types.html#projecttasks

Right now, there is no way to set custom dates for project tasks without children.

You can enable the `auto_types` parameter to dynamically change the task type:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_auto_types_config.html

If a `task` has a child task, it will become a `project` task. Projects without child tasks will become regular tasks.
You can check how it works in the following sample:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/04_customization/19_task_type.html